# The right way to make DynamoDB data searchable in Athena?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-athena

I need to have, a slowly changing, AWS DynamoDb periodically dumped on S3, for querying it on Athena. It needs to be ensured that data available to Athena is not much behind what's available on DynamoDb (maximum lag of 1 hour)

I am aware of the following two approaches:

1. Use EMR (from Data Pipeline) to [export](https://github.com/aws-samples/data-pipeline-samples/tree/master/samples/DynamoDBExport) the entire DynamoDb

   Advantage of this approach is that with a single EMR script (run hourly), compressed Parquet files, which are directly searchable on Athena, can be dumped on S3. However, a big disadvantage of this approach is that while only a small number of records change in an hour, the entire dump needs to be taken, requiring significantly higher read capacity in DynamoDb and higher EMR resources.
2. Use [DynamoDB Streams](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.Lambda.html) to reflect any changes in DynamoDb on S3.

   This has the advantage of not needing to process unchanged data on DynamoDb, thus reduces the need of significantly higher read capacity than whats needed in normal operations. However, a follow up script (probably another EMR job) would be needed to consolidate the per record files generated by DynamoDb streams, else performance of Athena gets severely impacted because of large number of files.

Are there any other approaches which can do better than these?

Answer (score 2):

I think the best solution from a performance/cost perspective would be to use DynamoDB Streams and a Glue Job to *consolidate* the files once a day (or once a week, depending on your data's velocity).

One downside in the DynamoDB Streams approach (and all solutions that read data incrementally) is that you have to handle the complexity of updating/deleting records from a Parquet file.

If your load is not exclusively "appending" new data to the table you should write any updated/deleted item somewhere (probably a DynamoDB Table or an S3 file) and let Glue delete those records before writing the consolidated file to S3.

All the actors will be:

a **Lambda** processing streams that should:

- write newly added items to Parquet files in S3,
- write updates (even *PutItem* on an existing item) and deletions to a DynamoDB table;

a **Glue Job** running less frequently that should:

- consolidate the many smaller files created by the first lambda into fewer bigger parquets,
- merge all update/delete operations logged in the DynamoDB table to the resulting parquet.

This results in much more effort than using EMR to dump the full table hourly: you should judge by yourself if it is worth it. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented the following data pipeline for real time data streaming to athena:

Dynamodb -> DynamoDB streams -> Lambda -> Kinesis Firehose -> s3 <- Athena

Do let me know if you have any doubts.

Comment: I have doubts.  DynamoDB is a key based lookup system.  FIrehose does not let you set your file names, so you can't update existing records in your S3 sync.  Meaning if you update your DynamoDB record 3 times, you will have 3 entries in your S3 bucket, one for each update.

Comment: Yes you are correct. For now you have to handle that via athena. Whatever duplicate records are entered you have to eliminate via querying. You can try deleting the line from the file while inserting but that is not recomended.